# recycle time reporting service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

by default the recycle time for reporting service is 720 minutes (12 hours). It is the reportserver.config file

> 720

Now it happens every 2 o'clock. so consequently, it happens twice a day 2 AM and 2 PM. Now the problem is we cannot have it recycled during business hours (2 PM). how do I set this to occur only @ 4 AM?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx

"RecycleTime: Specifies a recycle time for the application domain, measured in minutes. Valid values range from 0 to maximum integer. The default is 720."

I would interpret this as, after running X minutes, the app domain will recycle. If you want it to recycle every 24 hours, set it to 1440 minutes (24h x 60m).

If you want it to happen at 4am, I would assume you need to recycle it manually at 4AM. This would presumably reset the timer and force the auto recycle (every 1440 minutes) to occur again after 24 hours (or at 4am).